# "require" sub processes; how to stop them?

Tags: node.js

I want to send a class instance to a sub process that shall operate on the class and then later stop the process.

I have used the require for the module and sent the class instance as a parameter to an init function in the required module. This works as such, but it I want not to restart the complete program I cannot find a way to this.

I have limited experience from javascript. I did check the child_process functions but I newer got it to work. Also I tried something described here on stackoverflow aswell (see code).

```js
const myChildProgram = require("./myModule");

myClassInst = new myClass();

myChildProgram.init(myClassInst); //initialize and run sub processes this command launches other async processes.

//later in time/code
//stop all processes generated after the myChildProgram.init()

delete require.cache[require.resolve('./myModule')]; //not working
```

Would like to be able to stop the processes generated from the `myChildProgram.init()` call

Comment: What does `myModule` look like?  How is it starting the subprocess; spawn, exec, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Your code only shows loading a module - it doesn't show any subprocess. If there is code for creating a child process please show it.  FYI modules are not subprocesses - they are simply blocks of javascript code that have been loaded into the current process.

Comment: I think this cleared some parts out. I do not have a subprocess. I have a module.
This module starts subsctiptions etc. that have to be stopped. This means that I have to stop whatever goes on inside the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have modules and subprocesses confused.  A module is a block of javascript code that has been loaded into your current node process. There is no way to stop that code from the outside unless you kill your whole node process.

If you want a module to stop doing something it was doing, then the usual solution would be to export a function from that module that, when called, would execute code within the module to stop whatever it was doing.

We can only help more specifically if you show the actual code for the module and the operation that you want to stop.

Comment: Yes you are right. Can a module be re-required if everything in the previous require was stopped?

Comment: Or what is the option? Is it possible to send a class as a parameter as an argument? Basically this would mean some sort of shared memory space?

Comment: @MattsNorrbohm - Modules are in the same process and Javascript memory space as other modules so you can freely pass any Javascript data or class you want to another module.  In general, you wouldn't pass a class (but you can), but instead would `require()` in the dependent module to get access to a class.  If you actually have multiple processes involved somehow, then please show us that actual code so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MattsNorrbohm - We've gone as far as we can at the ***theoretical level***.  If you want more detailed help, show us your ACTUAL code and the actual thing you're trying to stop and then restart.  In general, you should do this with code in the module that you call rather than trying to stop a module or restart a module.  Modules just load code and run the initialization.  To do anything more than that, export functions from the module that do what you need.

Comment: this is all the answers I need. I have (guided by you all here at Stackoverflow) guided me in another direction for solving my challenge. Thanks!